# Java program .class error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am having trouble with getting this program to compile and could use some help. It is a simple program with what I am sure is a simple solution.

```
public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        char ch[] = new char[91];
        for(char a =65;a<ch.length;a++)
        {
            ch[a] = a;
        }
        for( a= 65;a<ch.length;a++)
        {
            char c = ch[];
            System.out.print(c+", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Compilation error messages are there for a reason.

Comment: Take a closely look at your second for loop.

Comment: Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        char ch[] = new char[91];
        for(char a =65;a<ch.length;a++)
        {
            ch[a] = a;
        }
        for(char a= 65;a<ch.length;a++)  // char
        {
            char c = ch[a];            //a
            System.out.print(c+", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z,